# AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'dfs'

Tags: python, vectorization

I attached the full error that I am receiving below and want to know what is causing this.

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-d356d4172c8c> in <module>
     23     save_dictionary(doc.tfs, "dfs_" + str(doc.id) + ".txt")
     24 
---> 25 vectorize("./textfiles")
     26 

<ipython-input-154-d356d4172c8c> in vectorize(data_path)
     14             Documents.append(doc)
     15 
---> 16     save_dictionary(doc.dfs, "tf_" + str(doc.id) + ".txt")
     17 
     18     dfs = {}

AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'dfs'
```

I also have attached the full code to my program to help troubleshoot my issue. I am not to sure what I would do would I need to do to fix this issue. If I change doc.dfs to doc.tfs it works but since dfs is a dictionary I don't think it works.

```
class Document: 
    def __init__(self, doc_id):
        # create a new document with its ID
        self.id = doc_id
        # create an empty dictionary 
        # that will hold the term frequency (TF) counts
        self.tfs = {}

    def tokenization(self, text):
        # split a title into words, 
        # using space " " as delimiter
        words = text.lower().split(" ")
        for word in words: 
            # for each word in the list
            if word in self.tfs: 
                # if it has been counted in the TF dictionary
                # add 1 to the count
                self.tfs[word] = self.tfs[word] + 1
            else:
                # if it has not been counted, 
                # initialize its TF with 1
                self.tfs[word] = 1

def save_dictionary(diction_data, file_path_name):
    f = open(file_path_name, "w+")

    for key in diction_data:
        # Separate the key from the frequency with a space and
        # add a newline to the end of each key value pair
        f.write(key + " " + str(diction_data[key]) + "\n")

    f.close()

def vectorize(data_path):
    Documents = []
    for i in range(1, 21):
        file_name = "./textfiles/"+ str(i) + ".txt"
            # create a new document with an ID
        doc = Document(i+1)
        #Read the files
        with open(file_name,'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
        #compute the term frequencies
        #read in the files contents
            doc.tokenization(text)
        # add the documents to the lists
            Documents.append(doc)

    save_dictionary(doc.tfs, "tf_" + str(doc.id) + ".txt")

    DFS = {}
    for doc in Documents:
        for word in doc.tfs:
            DFS[word] = DFS.get(word,0) + 1

    save_dictionary(doc.DFS, "DFS_" + str(doc.id) + ".txt")

vectorize("./textfiles")
```

I have looked at the class and I think the issue is coming from there. I am unsure what exactly is causing this problem but I would want whatever words not in tfs to be saved to dfs and then when I run it have files with .tfs and also .dfs files.

Comment: There are two things to point out while briefly looking over your question. 1. Your error-message references `doc.dfs` while your actual posted code has `doc.DFS`. They are most probably the same, only that you've changed the case of the variable, however we cannot know that for certain. 2. `save_dictionary` recerences `doc` where it's outside of it's scope (outside of the for-loop(s)). Please look at the help-page [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @HampusLarsson In the code DFS was uppercase on accident in my actual code its dfs lowercase correct. I am trying to figure out now where to put the save_dictionary to make it correct now.